# What is the callbackfn argument of ArrayMap function in v8's source code?

Tags: c++, v8

In builtins-array-gen.cc

```cpp
TF_BUILTIN(ArrayMap, ArrayBuiltinCodeStubAssembler) {
  Node* argc =
      ChangeInt32ToIntPtr(Parameter(BuiltinDescriptor::kArgumentsCount));
  CodeStubArguments args(this, argc);
  Node* context = Parameter(BuiltinDescriptor::kContext);
  Node* new_target = Parameter(BuiltinDescriptor::kNewTarget);
  Node* receiver = args.GetReceiver();

  Node* callbackfn = args.GetOptionalArgumentValue(0, UndefinedConstant());
  Node* this_arg = args.GetOptionalArgumentValue(1, UndefinedConstant());
  InitIteratingArrayBuiltinBody(context, receiver, callbackfn, this_arg,
                                new_target, argc);
  GenerateIteratingArrayBuiltinBody(
      "Array.prototype.map", &ArrayBuiltinCodeStubAssembler::MapResultGenerator,
      &ArrayBuiltinCodeStubAssembler::MapProcessor,
      &ArrayBuiltinCodeStubAssembler::NullPostLoopAction,
      Builtins::CallableFor(isolate(), Builtins::kArrayMapLoopContinuation));
}
```

I have no any Idea about what this `callbackfn` means.

Is this `this_arg` this pointer?

But in my mind, the first argument should be `this` pointer, so I am confused.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for `Array.prototype.map`: its signature is:

```
arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {...} [, thisArg])
```

And that's precisely what's reflected in the builtin you found, just expressed in V8's internal notation.

`receiver` is the receiver of the call, i.e. the array that you call `.map` on, `arr` in the MDN example.

`callbackfn` is the callback function, `callback` as MDN calls it.

`this_arg` is the optional `thisArg` as MDN calls it.

The fact that `callbackfn` is considered optional by that code doesn't reflect (and doesn't need to reflect) the specification; it's simply the most convenient way to safely handle the case where the user didn't pass a callback function. What matters is the resulting behavior, which is that a `TypeError` is thrown when `callbackfn` is not callable or missing (which is a special case of "not callable", because missing parameters are undefined, and undefined is not a function).

Comment: thanks for your help. And there is another question, how does v8 judge what is the fastJSArray?

Comment: There are probably various definitions depending on context; usually it means "the elements backing store is not in dictionary mode".